# How Can I Get the Number of Open Tabs, in IE8, Programatically?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I need to get the Number of Tabs in the Current IE Window.
The programming language doesn't matter, as long as it's possible to do it programatically :)

I use Windows XP SP3.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Security restrictions prevent you from doing this client side.

The only way you could do this would be by doing an addon.

Comment: Hmm.. Will IE's DOM allow it?